# Jenkins Amazon EC2 Plugin Invalid availability zone: [us-east-1]

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, cloudbees

I am running Jenkins through beanstalk with a mounted volume.  I have configured it to always setup inside us-east-1a.  I am trying to configure Amazon EC2 Plugin to spin up slaves to run the jobs on, but currently I'm coming up with errors that I do not know how to debug.

Inside the System Logs for Jenkins I get

```
Feb 24, 2017 5:33:29 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud provision
Attempting to provision slave from template hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate@c2fd792 
needed by excess workload of 1 units of label 'ec2'
Feb 24, 2017 5:33:29 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate
logProvisionInfo
Considering launching ami-c620f0d0 for template Jenkins Slave AMI
(Ubuntu 16.04, JDK, Docker)
Feb 24, 2017 5:33:29 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate
logProvisionInfo
Setting Instance Initiated Shutdown Behavior :
ShutdownBehavior.Terminate
Feb 24, 2017 5:33:29 PM WARNING hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud provision
Exception during provisioning
com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: Invalid
availability zone: [us-east-1] (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400;
Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 20701759-6830-463b-bcd6-85c2ba2b4741)
```

The part that I think is giving me the trouble is the availability zone.  Though I do not know how to change something for this to correct the issue.  I was trying to follow [CloudBees Jenkins Slaves](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/setting-jenkins-ec2-slaves).  It seems like everything up to making the request works, but stops with an AWS error.  I tagged the job as ec2 and that seems to pick up and run during the build job.  I have tested the connection under the Cloud option when setting up and get a Success from it.  After choosing the availability zone there it seems to be correct.  I have checked the AMI and it pulls the correct image to use.  I have added the pem file to Jenkins that is stored and added to the AMI image that was created.

Where or what do I need to look at to get this running?  Is there something in aws that I have not configured correctly?  I followed the article without any setup trouble.  All help is appreciated.

Comment: If you need to choose an availability zone (and not just a region), I'm missing the letter specifying a zone within your region. So probably, it should be us-east-1a, us-east-1b and so on.

Comment: Thanks but I looked into that.  Jenkins and the plugin only gives you a drop down that it has been pre-populated and the only options are just the regions.  us-east-1 and so forth.  Is there a different place to change that?

Comment: hi @lumberjacked even I am also facing the same problem.Are you able to find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

The EC2 plugin gives you the drop-down for region, but a few fields below there is the availability zone section where you can specify for example us-east-1a, or 1b, or 1c etc.

This fixed my issue:

[image: IMG Example]